# R: Apply-like function for dataframe rows when columns vary

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a sparse data frame `example`.  It has five data columns, but each row has just two entries, distributed randomly amongst the columns:

```
id  a   b   c   d   e
1   NA  10  NA  NA  1
2   6   NA  10  NA  NA
3   3   NA  NA  2   NA
4   NA  NA  9   4   NA
5   NA  NA  1   NA  5
```

I want to return a dataframe with just two data columns, the values in each row:

```
id  val1    val2
1   10      1
2   6       10
3   3       2
4   9       4
5   1       5
```

This is possible with a `for` loop.  But my real data is quite large, so I'd like to make an `apply`-like function.  Everything I've seen assumes you know which columns you'll be using.  I tried making my own one-row function and then using `apply`, but I kept getting error "incorrect number of dimensions".

Comment: No outside library, completely vectorized. `t(apply(example, 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
d1 <- setNames(data.frame(example$id,t(apply(example[-1], 1,
                        function(x) x[!is.na(x)]))),
                                 c('id', 'val1', 'val2'))
d1
#  id val1 val2
#1  1   10    1
#2  2    6   10
#3  3    3    2
#4  4    9    4
#5  5    1    5
```

Or you could convert to 'long' format and then reconvert back to 'wide'

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(example), id.var='id', na.rm=TRUE)[,
           ind:=paste0('val', 1:.N) , id], id~ind, value.var='value')
#    id val1 val2
#1:  1   10    1
#2:  2    6   10
#3:  3    3    2
#4:  4    9    4
#5:  5    1    5
```

#### data

```
example <- structure(list(id = 1:5, a = c(NA, 6L, 3L, NA, NA),
b = c(10L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), c = c(NA, 10L, NA, 9L, 1L), d = c(NA, NA, 2L, 
4L, NA), e = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, 5L)), .Names = c("id", "a", "b", 
"c", "d", "e"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a very fast approach:

```
temp <- t(example[-1])  # Matrix of all columns other than the first, transposed
cbind(example[1],       # Bind the first column with a two-column matrix
                        # created by using is.na and which
      matrix(temp[which(!is.na(temp), arr.ind = TRUE)], 
             ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
#   id  1  2
# 1  1 10  1
# 2  2  6 10
# 3  3  3  2
# 4  4  9  4
# 5  5  1  5
```

In a quick test with a dataset of 5 million rows, it performs faster than both the "data.table" and `apply` approaches.